# JPA: Enums in named queries

Tags: java, jpa, enums, named-query

I have an Entity like this:

```
package it.infogroup.vertenze.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "RICHIESTE_ESPORTAZIONE_ISIDORO")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "findFlussoDatiGeneraliByStato",
                    query = "select r from RichiestaEsportazioneIsidoro r 
                            where r.stato = it.infogroup.vertenze.entities.
                            RichiestaEsportazioneIsidoro$StatoRichiesta.NEW
                            or r.stato = it.infogroup.vertenze.entities.
                            RichiestaEsportazioneIsidoro$StatoRichiesta.FAIL
                            and r.tipoFlusso = it.infogroup.vertenze.entities.
                            RichiestaEsportazioneIsidoro$TipoFlusso.DATI_GENERALI"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "findFlussoAccantonamentiByStato",
                   query = "select r from RichiestaEsportazioneIsidoro r
                            where r.stato = it.infogroup.vertenze.entities.
                            RichiestaEsportazioneIsidoro$StatoRichiesta.NEW
                            or r.stato = it.infogroup.vertenze.entities.
                            RichiestaEsportazioneIsidoro$StatoRichiesta.FAIL
                            and r.tipoFlusso = it.infogroup.vertenze.entities.
                            RichiestaEsportazioneIsidoro$TipoFlusso.ACCANTONAMENTI")
})
public class RichiestaEsportazioneIsidoro implements Serializable {

 public final static String QUERY_FIND_BY_LOTTO_AND_STATO =
                                                     "findRichiestaByLottoAndStato";

  public enum StatoRichiesta {
    NEW,
    ELAB,
    SENT,
    FAIL
  }

    public enum TipoFlusso {
        DATI_GENERALI,
        ACCANTONAMENTI
    }
```

On deploying I'm getting this error:

```
01/12/2014 16:59 [ERROR]: org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl -
                 Error in named query: findFlussoAccantonamentiByStato
                 org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
                 unexpected token: . near line 1, column 167 [select r from
                 it.infogroup.vertenze.entities.RichiestaEsportazioneIsidoro r
                 where r.stato = it.infogroup.vertenze.entities.
                 RichiestaEsportazioneIsidoro$StatoRichiesta.NEW
                 or r.stato = it.infogroup.vertenze.entities.
                 RichiestaEsportazioneIsidoro$StatoRichiesta.FAIL
                 and r.tipoFlusso = it.infogroup.vertenze.entities.
                 RichiestaEsportazioneIsidoro$TipoFlusso.ACCANTONAMENTI]
```

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: That should work, can you show how you annotated the enum fields in `RichiestaEsportazioneIsidoro`?

Comment: I annotated them with `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is related to this hibernate bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8368

You're using a JPQL reserved word `NEW` for your enum value.
Try using another name for new, hibernate fail to handle such case.

Below you can check the list of JPQL reserved words.
https://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_from_identifiers

Comment: Just to mention that your "checker" link is for SQL keywords NOT for JPQL keywords (which is what is the issue here).